# How to use NancyFx with Authentification on Xamarin

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, nancy

I am facing a problem, i have a application ASP.net with NancyFX for my WebSite. I use the authentification and it works.
But now, i build a mobile application (with Xamarin). The problem is : How to use authentification ?

If to the start of my module, i use :

```
this.RequiresAuthentication();
```

Also, i am redirect on login webpage. (the content's request)

I tried to set the header Authorization like this :

```
var authData = string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password);
var authHeaderValue = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(authData));
var headerAuth = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", authHeaderValue);
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = headerAuth;
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use [stateles auth](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Stateless-authentication) or something similar.